# Python - how to count number of uppercase letters in a string that is in a list

Tags: python, string, list, count, uppercase

For example, if I have this list:

```
s = ["Johnny and Annie", "Great job guys", "She and I"]
```

how can I make Python count the number of uppercase letters in each element of this list? For this example, Python should return 2, 1, 2.

This is my code so far:

```
def poisci_pare(besedilo):
x = []
seznam = []
t = re.split("[.]", besedilo)
for e in t:
    x = x + e.split()
for s in x:
    if s == s.capitalize() and not s.startswith('"'):
        seznam.append(s)
```

This function makes a list where it separates sentences by dots and then it filters out all the uppercase words in it, but I've no idea how to make it count the uppercase letters..

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper

Comment: What did you try so far? (You have to show some effort first, since this is not a code writing service.)

Comment: I've posted my code so far and I've managed to make 3 lists; 1 separates all the sentences by dots, one splits all the words in these sentences and the last list filters out all the uppercase lettered words, but now I'm stuck and I can't get it to count how many there are in a sentence.. I've tried .isupper but it isn't exactly helpful because I need an exact count and not True/False.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[sum([c.isupper() for c in a]) for a in s]
```

for your example it will output:

```
[2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

a straightforward way could be:

- loop through each string in your list
- initialize a counter of upper case letters for the current string
- loop through each character in the list and check if it `isupper`
- update the current string's counter with the number of `isupper` found